# OpenMP: Looping Through 'std::map' Benchmark (Dynamic Scheduling)

Tags: c++, multithreading, parallel-processing, multiprocessing, openmp

I have to loop through `std::map` and the job that has to be done within each iteration has the following properties:

1. The amount of work varies within each iteration;
2. Does not need any synchronization between threads.

Looks like perfect scenario for dynamic scheduling, doesn't it?

However, non-random access iterators (such as `std::map` has) are notorious of troubling one as far as loop parallelization with OpenMP is concerned. For me the performance of this particular code is going to be critical, therefore in search for the most efficient solution I've created the following benchmark:

```
#include <omp.h>

#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <vector>

#define COUNT 0x00006FFF

#define UNUSED(variable) (void)(variable)

using std::map;
using std::vector;

void test1(map<int, vector<int> >& m) {
  double time = omp_get_wtime();

  map<int, vector<int> >::iterator iterator = m.begin();

#pragma omp parallel
#pragma omp for schedule(dynamic, 1) nowait
  for (size_t i = 0; i < m.size(); ++i) {
    vector<int>* v;
#pragma omp critical
    v = &iterator->second;

    for (size_t j = 0; j < v->size(); ++j) {
      (*v)[j] = j;
    }

#pragma omp critical
    iterator++;
  }

  printf("Test #1: %f s\n", (omp_get_wtime() - time));
}

void test2(map<int, vector<int> >& m) {
  double time = omp_get_wtime();

#pragma omp parallel
  {
    for (map<int, vector<int> >::iterator i = m.begin(); i != m.end(); ++i) {
#pragma omp single nowait
      {
        vector<int>& v = i->second;

        for (size_t j = 0; j < v.size(); ++j) {
          v[j] = j;
        }
      }
    }
  }

  printf("Test #2: %f s\n", (omp_get_wtime() - time));
}

void test3(map<int, vector<int> >& m) {
  double time = omp_get_wtime();

#pragma omp parallel
  {
    int thread_count = omp_get_num_threads();
    int thread_num = omp_get_thread_num();
    size_t chunk_size = m.size() / thread_count;
    map<int, vector<int> >::iterator begin = m.begin();
    std::advance(begin, thread_num * chunk_size);
    map<int, vector<int> >::iterator end = begin;
    if (thread_num == thread_count - 1)
      end = m.end();
    else
      std::advance(end, chunk_size);

    for (map<int, vector<int> >::iterator i = begin; i != end; ++i) {
      vector<int>& v = i->second;

      for (size_t j = 0; j < v.size(); ++j) {
        v[j] = j;
      }
    }
  }

  printf("Test #3: %f s\n", (omp_get_wtime() - time));
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  UNUSED(argc);
  UNUSED(argv);

  map<int, vector<int> > m;

  for (int i = 0; i < COUNT; ++i) {
    m[i] = vector<int>(i);
  }

  test1(m);
  test2(m);
  test3(m);
}
```

There are 3 possible variants that I could come up with to imitate my task. The code is very simple and speaks for itself, please take a look at it. I've ran the tests several times and here are my results:

```
Test #1: 0.169000 s
Test #2: 0.203000 s
Test #3: 0.194000 s

Test #1: 0.167000 s
Test #2: 0.203000 s
Test #3: 0.191000 s

Test #1: 0.182000 s
Test #2: 0.202000 s
Test #3: 0.197000 s

Test #1: 0.167000 s
Test #2: 0.187000 s
Test #3: 0.211000 s

Test #1: 0.168000 s
Test #2: 0.195000 s
Test #3: 0.192000 s

Test #1: 0.166000 s
Test #2: 0.197000 s
Test #3: 0.199000 s

Test #1: 0.184000 s
Test #2: 0.198000 s
Test #3: 0.199000 s

Test #1: 0.167000 s
Test #2: 0.202000 s
Test #3: 0.207000 s
```

I'm posting this question because I found these results peculiar and absolutely unexpected:

1. Expected test #2 to be the fastest as it does not use critical section as test #1 does;
2. Expected test #3 to be the slowest as it does not really utilize dynamic scheduling, but rather relies on static distribution of jobs (which is done manually);
3. Could have never expected that test #2 would be roughly equivalent to test #3 and sometimes even worse.

The questions are:

1. Am I missing anything?
2. Could you explain the test results?
3. Do you have a better idea of parallelization here?

Comment: Have you tried benchmarking with unordered_map?

Comment: @Leeor, why would I? It changes nothing in this case. This question  is not about data structure holy war. It is about parallelization strategies. Finally, I'm not interested in `unordered_map` for this particular task.

Answer (score 2):

> 3. Do you have a better idea of parallelization here?

You might try imitating `schedule(static,1)` of an OpenMP loop, i.e. instead of processing a big chunk of successive iterations, a thread processes iterations with `thread_count` stride. Here is the code:

```
void test4(map<int, vector<int> >& m) {
  double time = omp_get_wtime();

#pragma omp parallel
  {
    int thread_count = omp_get_num_threads();
    int thread_num = omp_get_thread_num();
    size_t map_size = m.size();
    map<int, vector<int> >::iterator it = m.begin();
    std::advance(it, thread_num);

    for (int i = thread_num; i < map_size; i+=thread_count) {
      vector<int>& v = it->second;

      for (size_t j = 0; j < v.size(); ++j) {
        v[j] = j;
      }

      if( i+thread_count < map_size ) std::advance(it, thread_count);
    }
  }

  printf("Test #4: %f s\n", (omp_get_wtime() - time));
}
```

`schedule(static,1)` provides better load balancing than `schedule(static)` in case the amount of work is increasing or decreasing over the iteration space. This is the case for your test workload. And in case the amount of work per iteration is random, these two strategies should on average give the same balancing.

Another variant is to imitate `schedule(dynamic)` with the help of an atomic counter. The code:

```
void test5(map<int, vector<int> >& m) {
  double time = omp_get_wtime();
  int count = 0;
#pragma omp parallel shared(count)
  {
    int i;
    int i_old = 0;
    size_t map_size = m.size();
    map<int, vector<int> >::iterator it = m.begin();

#pragma omp atomic capture
    i = count++;

    while (i < map_size) {
      std::advance(it, i-i_old);
      vector<int>& v = it->second;

      for (size_t j = 0; j < v.size(); ++j) {
        v[j] = j;
      }

      i_old = i;
#pragma omp atomic capture
      i = count++;
    }
  }

  printf("Test #5: %f s\n", (omp_get_wtime() - time));
}
```

in a loop, a thread decides how much it should advance its local iterator over the map. The thread first atomically increments the counter and takes its previous value, thus obtaining the iteration index, then advances the iterator by the difference between the new index and the previous one. The loop repeats until the counter is increased above the map size.